# Can I write ruby 2.3.7 scripts that are backward compatible with 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby

Up till now, I've been writing all my scripts in POSIX shell so that I can run them on all the machines I use (macOS, various Linuxes, FreeBSD). I like to have a unified experience where I can pull down my dotfiles from git, and have all my settings and scripts ready to go.

However, POSIX shell is a really irritating language, and I've been considering switching to Ruby for my scripting needs. Unfortunately before I even got started, I realized that macOS ships with Ruby 2.3.7, and one of the machines I often need to use only has Ruby 1.8.7. It's a school machine for which I do not have sudo access, so I can't install a later version of Ruby.

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to write Ruby scripts that will run on both 1.8.7 and 2.3.7 (and hopefully everything in between)? Is there a set of guidelines I can follow that will help me avoid incompatible language features?

Comment: Don't use features added in later Ruby. This includes language and library functionality.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've heard that 1.9 broke compatibility with 1.8. Unless I misunderstand, that implies that there are things that work in 1.8 that don't work in 1.9. Therefore it's more complicated than just writing 1.8 code, because there are some things that will not work on later versions.

Comment: Other than map order there's nothing significant iirc. The changes are all documented--if you've been doing everything in bash then it's unlikely you're going to be doing much that'll stress compatibility. Plus it's trivial to install multiple versions of Ruby to test anyway. SO isn't really the best place to ask for the laundry list of Ruby version changes--just look at the docs, change logs for the major releases, and blog posts discussing the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, provided you restrict yourself to the intersection of the language and library features of Ruby 1.8.7, Ruby 2.3.7, and everything in between.

The last big break of backwards-compatibility was the jump from Ruby 1.8 to Ruby 1.9. String handling was completely changed, so anything to do with text processing, you need to be very careful.

Of the top of my head:

- In Ruby 1.8, strings are considered to be a sequence of bytes. In Ruby 1.9. strings are a factory for different iterators, iterating in terms of code points, characters, or bytes.
- Therefore, in Ruby 1.9, strings are no longer `Enumerable`.
- Indexing into a string will return an `Integer` in Ruby 1.8 and a single-character `String` in Ruby 1.9.
- Character literals (e.g. `?a`) will evaluate to an `Integer` in Ruby 1.8 and a single-character `String` in Ruby 1.9.
- In Ruby 1.8, all strings are assumed to be in the same encoding (usually ASCII, but can be changed to a very limited set, namely UTF-8 and a couple of Asian encodings). Ruby 1.9 is fully encoding-aware, each string has its own separate encoding, each I/O stream has two encodings (an internal one and an external one) and each source file has a separate encoding.

Your best bet might be to restrict yourself to use only what is specified in the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html). The spec was specifically written so that all existing Ruby implementations at the time (MRI, YARV, IronRuby, JRuby, MacRuby, Rubinius) would automatically be compliant, which basically means that the spec only specifies the minimal required subset of the intersection of Ruby 1.8.6, Ruby 1.8.7, and Ruby 1.9.0.

Since there haven't been any backwards-incompatible changes since then, you can be assured that your code will work on all versions from Ruby 1.8.6 up to (but excluding) 3.0, and on all ISO-compliant Ruby implementations, which are as far as I know MRI, YARV, JRuby, IronRuby, Rubinius, MacRuby, MRuby, MagLev, and TruffleRuby.